# Not able to automatically set a checkbutton as checked on a value getting updated

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue js template that contains two radio buttons that are initially unchecked. Once the widgets get rendered, I want one of the radio buttons to be checked automatically on a value being updated after retrieving it from the backend server.

Here is the code as seen below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CCard class="card">
      <CCardHeader>{{ $t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.HEADER") }}</CCardHeader>
      <CCardBody>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td class="index">
              <strong>
                {{ $t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.DISBURSEMENT_INDEX") }}
              </strong>
              <img
                src="@/assets/img/blue-circle.svg"
                class="info pointer-on-hover"
                v-c-tooltip="{
                  html: true,
                  content: getDisbursementTooltipContent,
                  active: false,
                  placement: 'top',
                }"
              >
            </td>
            <td class="category">
              <fieldset id="disbursement-group">
                <input
                  id="whatsapp"
                  type="radio"
                  name="disbursement-group"
                  value="whatsapp"
                  @change="selectDisbursementPreference"
                  :checked="disbursementPreference === whatsapp"
                >
                <span class="text">Whatsapp</span>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td class="category">
              <fieldset id="disbursement-group">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  type="radio"
                  name="disbursement-group"
                  value="email"
                  @change="selectDisbursementPreference"
                  :checked="disbursementPreference === email"
                >
                <span class="text">Email</span>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <br>
          <tr hidden>
            <td class="index">
              <strong>
                {{ $t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.SETTLEMENT_INDEX") }}
              </strong>
              <img
                src="@/assets/img/blue-circle.svg"
                class="info pointer-on-hover"
                v-c-tooltip="{
                  html: true,
                  content: getSettlementTooltipContent,
                  active: false,
                  placement: 'bottom',
                }"
              >
            </td>
            <td class="category">
              <fieldset id="settlement-group">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="settlement-group"
                  value="email"
                  @change="selectSettlementPreference"
                  :checked="settlementPreference === email"
                >
                <span class="text">{{ $t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.YES") }}</span>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
              <fieldset id="settlement-group">
                <input
                  value="none"
                  type="radio"
                  name="settlement-group"
                  @change="selectSettlementPreference"
                  :checked="settlementPreference === none"
                >
                <span class="text">{{ $t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.NO") }}</span>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td
              v-if="isEmailInputVisible"
              class="email-column"
            >
              <strong>Email</strong>
              <input
                type="text"
                v-model="emailRecepients"
              >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </CCardBody>
    </CCard>
    <CButton
      color="durianprimary"
      class="button"
      @click="savePreferences"
      :disabled="isSaveButtonDisabled"
    >
      {{ $t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.SAVE") }}
    </CButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Notifications",
  data() {
    return {
      disbursementPreference: "",
      whatsapp: constant.WHATSAPP,
      email: constant.EMAIL,
      none: constant.TEXT_NONE,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    selectDisbursementPreference(event) {
      this.disbursementPreference = event.target.value;
    },
    setDisbursementPreference(data) {
      if (!data.is_available) {
        return;
      }
      const length = data.types.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (data.types[i].is_enabled) {
          this.disbursementPreference = data.types[i].type;
          return;
        }
      }
    },
    createDisbursementPreferencePayload() {
      const disbursementPreferenceLength =
        constant.DISBURSEMENT_PREFERENCE_TYPES.length;
      const types = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < disbursementPreferenceLength; i++) {
        if (
          constant.DISBURSEMENT_PREFERENCE_TYPES[i] ===
          this.disbursementPreference
        ) {
          types.push({
            type: constant.DISBURSEMENT_PREFERENCE_TYPES[i],
            is_enabled: true,
          });
        } else {
          types.push({
            type: constant.DISBURSEMENT_PREFERENCE_TYPES[i],
            is_enabled: false,
          });
        }
      }
      return { is_available: true, types: types };
    },
    createRequestPayload() {
      const disbursementPayload = this.createDisbursementPreferencePayload();

      return {
        disbursement: disbursementPayload,
      };
    },
    async savePreferences() {
       ....
    },
    async getPreferences() {
       ....
    },
  },

  computed: {
    getDisbursementTooltipContent() {
      return `${this.$t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.DISBURSEMENT")}`;
    },
    getSettlementTooltipContent() {
      return `${this.$t("SETTINGS.NOTIFICATIONS.SETTLEMENT")}`;
    },
    isEmailInputVisible() {
      return this.settlementPreference === this.email;
    },
    getEmailRecipients() {
      let recipientsString = "";
      const length = this.settlementEmailReceipients.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        recipientsString += this.settlementEmailReceipients[i] + ";";
      }
      return recipientsString;
    },
    isSaveButtonDisabled() {
      return (
        this.emailRecepients.length === 0 &&
        this.settlementPreference === constant.EMAIL
      );
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPreferences();
  },
};
</script>
```

I have tried to automatically set either of the check buttons with the following code pieces:

```
   watch : {
         disbursementPreference:function(val) {
             console.log("watch value has been changed => ",val);
             document.getElementById(val).checked = true;
         },
   },
```

and

```
  updated() {
    console.log("value that I am trying to test => ",this.disbursementPreference);
    document.getElementById(this.disbursementPreference).checked = true;
  },
```

But the thing is, while the above code captures the changes made to the `disbursementPreference` variable, the result still remains the same because **the widgets have not been rendered yet**.

Is there a way to solve the above problem? I tried `window.onload` but I think rendering in vue.js is somewhat different as far as I know.

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Please do let me know thanks.

P.S : I have not added all of the template code for proprietary reasons.

Comment: document.getElementById(val).checked = true ?? Why don't you use a data prop for this? Anyway, does your watch get triggered? What do you want to achieve with updated()?

Comment: The thing is, I am making an API call the get details inside the template.

Comment: I don't get why an API call should make a difference. If you define it in your data first and then fill it in, that data prop will be responsive. If you create another reference after loading, the reference will not update and thus not be responsive.